# Were flu vaccines 9% effective for the elderly in 2013?

Tags: vaccines, flu

I recently saw [this video](http://www.ihealthtube.com/aspx/viewvideo.aspx?v=97f4bd533d084ad0) featuring Robert Scott Bell, where he basically says that the flu shot is not terribly effective.

Under the video is this description, in part:

> Reports in 2013 state that flu shots were only 9% effective for the elderly.

9% sounds dismal. Is that actually the case? Do the reports show that in early 2013 the flu shot was only 9% effective in the elderly?

Comment: related http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/278/6876

Comment: 9% sounds darn good in some comparisons? ["Vaccine effectiveness estimate %, Age ≥ 65 years: ***−32.9%***"](https://www.eurosurveillance.org/content/10.2807/1560-7917.ES2015.20.5.21024?crawler=true&mimetype=application/pdf) A cynic would say that shot formula *was* terribly effective. Although…

Answer (score 2):

*Is that actually the case?* : Maybe

*Do the reports show that in early 2013 the flu shot was only 9% effective in the elderly?* : No

It might be the case that the flu shot's effectiveness was only 9% in the elderly, but the analysis that the CDC does isn't able to support a statement as strong as "the flu shot's effectiveness in group X is Y%". They can only give  ranges.

What *is* true is that the [CDC's point estimate for the flu vaccine effectiveness against the 2013 flu A (H3N2)](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/about/season/flu-season-2012-2013.htm) in people aged 65 or older is 9%, with a 95% confidence interval that spans from -84% to 55%. They suggest interpreting these results with caution.

In more general terms, the CDC says the following things:

> CDC's vaccine effectiveness study measured lower vaccine effectiveness among people 65 and older against flu A this season than it did among other age groups.
>
> [...]
>
> One possible explanation for this is that some older people did not mount an effective immune response to the flu A (H3N2) component of this season’s vaccine; however, it’s not possible to say this for certain.

Against flu B, effectiveness in the 65 and older age group was found to be similar to that in other age groups: 67% with a 95% confidence interval that spans from 51% to 78%.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what? If the shot is given to 1000 people how many are effectively protected? If it's 9% then I would think 90 people are protected.

Comment: The CDC's measure of vaccine effectiveness represents the reduction in risk provided by the flu vaccine: http://www.cdc.gov/flu/about/qa/vaccineeffect.htm#present-data

Comment: How many people are protected is a more complicated question, and would require analyzing the hampered spread of a disease through a partially vaccinated population vs a completely unvaccinated population. For example, even if the vaccine was 100% effective, and given to 400 people in a 1000 person population, that would give some protection to the entire population because the virus can't easily be passed on through those 400 vaccinated people.

Comment: What does it mean for the confidence interval to include negative values? How does one interpret a statement like that?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank presumably negative effectiveness would indicate that it increased flu cases. In any case the confidence interval is so wide I wouldn't draw conclusions from this

Comment: @user253751 you can draw the conclusion that it’s basically a useless vaccine.

Comment: @froimovi It could be 55% effective. There's a 5% probability it's greater than 55%. The study is not powerful enough.